# Insert data from XML into SQL table with having Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have existing table named **questionTbl** whose schema is as follows:

```
quesid int identity(1,1) not null,
ques varchar(3000),
catid int,
timestamp datetime
```

now the XML data has to insert into this table which is like:

```
<root>
    <data>
        <ques>JHello 1</ques>
        <catid>1</catid>
    </data>
    <data>
        <ques>hellow2</ques>
        <catid>1</catid>
    </data>
</root>
```

I am trying to create a procedure by i am getting error of invalid column

```
create proc insertQuesXML
@xmlData xml 
as
    insert into ques_tbl values (ques, catid, getdate())
select 

   ques = x.value('ques[1]', 'varchar(3000)') ,
 catid =  x.value('catid[1]', 'int')
  from  @xmlData.nodes('//root/data') as xmlData(x)
```

**--error**

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insertQuesXML, Line 4
Invalid column name 'ques'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insertQuesXML, Line 4
Invalid column name 'catid'.
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement should be like this `insert into ques_tbl (ques, catid, timestamp) ` and you need to have one more column in your `SELECT` list which should be inserted into `timestamp`

Comment: Thank i have done...but not luck

Comment: Edit what you have done with error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` syntax is not correct, when you want to insert using `SELECT`, you don't need to use `VALUES`

Change your `INSERT` statement like following

```
insert into ques_tbl   (ques, catid, [timestamp]) 
select ques = x.value('ques[1]', 'varchar(3000)'), 
       catid = x.value('catid[1]', 'int'), 
       Getdate() 
from   @xmlData.nodes('//root/data') as xmlData(x)
```

Working Demo [here](http://rextester.com/BLE84280)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following SQL XML query for parsing your XML data into a tabular format

```
select 
    x.value('ques[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ques,
    x.value('catid[1]', 'int') as catid
from @xmlData.nodes('/root/data') as myXML(x)
```

So INSERT statement can be as follows

```
Insert Into QuestionTbl
select 
    x.value('ques[1]', 'varchar(100)') as ques,
    x.value('catid[1]', 'int') as catid,
    getdate()
from @xmlData.nodes('/root/data') as myXML(x)
```